# TinyMCE, проверка ввода текста

Tags: php, tinymce, html

Здравствуйте товарищи!

Возник вопрос, как избежать ввода "левых" данных через редактор TinyMCE. Как известно все данные из редактора передаются в html формате. Меня интересует как избежать попадения чужого кода в таблицу, и потом непосредственно вывод из нее. На данный момент у меня передается значение из textarea через метод POST без какой либо проверки:

```
$text = $_POST[text];
```

Может есть регулярка какая, или функция, в общем ищу совета!

Comment: Левые данные - это SQL injection или незакрытые теги/скрипты?

Answer (score 1):

Берем

```
"левые данные"
```

и

```
"удаляем левые данные"
```

о каких данных речь идет-то?

```
 $text = add_slashes($_POST[text]); 
 $text = trim($_POST[text]);
```

Что тебе проверять то нужно?

**Исходя из заданного вопроса**

```
Здравствуйте товарищи!

Возник вопрос, как избежать ввода "левых" данных через редактор TinyMCE. Как известно все данные из редактора передаются в html формате. Меня интересует как избежать попадения чужого кода в таблицу, и потом непосредственно вывод из нее. На данный момент у меня передается значение из textarea через метод POST без какой либо проверки:

$text = $_POST[text];
Может есть регулярка какая, или функция, в общем ищу совета!
```

**Не написано что редактор используется на сайте.** Так что понять что проверять непонятно, я этот редактор обычно использую только для админки, там проверять не нужно. На стороне сайта можно обойтись более простой формой и не использовать тинимси.

Так что минусы за ответ считаю неуместными, хотя мне пофиг.

А вот неправильно сформулированный вопрос - считаю глупым.

Comment: Ну по-любому что-бы не всунули js-коды.

Comment: В Вопросе нужно писать, откуда идут данные, я тинимси на сайте не юзаю только в админке, по этому и ответил так.

Comment: данные идут из обычного поля <textarea name="text"></textarea>, передается методом POST, через TinyMCE получается обычный форматированный html. Вот и вопрос отсюда, как защитить данные, что-бы не было возможности заюзать быдлокод!

Comment: Что-то я не пойму за что минусуют, и кто использует на сайте в комментах тинимси?

Не проще что-то простое юзать? или 30 строк кода на JS это безумно сложно? я про вставку BB кодов, пишется же легко.

Comment: Пишется то легко, это не вопрос, но, как ты обьяснишь 40-60 летним преподам, что такое bbcode и как их использовать=)))? И я про то, лучше что-то полегче для них)

Comment: Не всегда легкое залог хорошего.

А минусуют за то что не понимают вот и все.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если совсем правильно, то нужно включить TinyMCE в режиме редактирования bbcode и уже на сервере распарсить. в ином случае, вам что-то таки всунут

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

И потенциальная проблема не в TinyMCE, а в том, что все это происходит на стороне клиента. Фильтровать пользовательский ввод нужно на стороне сервера.

Самое основное: закрыть открытые теги и вырезать небезопасные. А, еще лучше, ограничить парсером набор возможных тегов и их атрибутов, а остальное удалять.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте доступ к графическому редактору только авторизованным пользователям. Остальные пусть используют обычное текстовое поле. В использование такого редактора есть и другие проблемы с безопасностью, например, встроенный файл менеджер, через который можно загрузить, например, php shell и порутать весь сайт.